# apache camel variable ${body} gets not converted after unmarshalling

Tags: java, jaxb, apache-camel

In my RouteBuilder I have this:

```
JaxbDataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat(); 
jaxb.setContext(JAXBContext.newInstance(MyClass.class));
from("direct:start")
   .unmarshal(jaxb)
   .process(new MyProcessor())
   .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "test.Test", "${body}")
...
```

MyProcessor simply does:

```
MyClass myClass = exchange.getIn().getBody(MyClass.class);
LOGGER.info("Converted to: {}", myClass );
```

Well, while the LOGGER in my Processor logs myClass.toString(), the log component in the route logs the original XML message body. Now I am a little bit confused. If I set a breakpoint in MyProcessor, then I can see that exchange.getIn().getBody(MyClass.class) really holds an Instance of MyClass. But why is after that the ${body} in the log component still XML?

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: See this FAQ it may help: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: Thanks Claus, but using `streamCaching()` in my route does not change the behaviour that the ${body} still is in XML-Format.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because you have not set the body on the exchange to whatever it is you want. You have only done a "getBody", hence the original xml is still the body on the exchange.

Can you change it to the following:

```
MyClass myClass = exchange.getIn().getBody(MyClass.class);
LOGGER.info("Converted to: {}", myClass );
exchange.getIn().setBody(myClass.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately: `exchange.getIn().setBody(myClass);` doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, with `myClass.toString()` it works but then I have a String as body in the message. I thought it is possible to work with objects here. I want to do further processing stuff etc. and therefore I need the JAXB object not a String.

Comment: Sure you can, but you wanted to log the body outside of the processor. If you send the object, then it won't look good. Hence for logging, it needs to be string. But for processing and and other stuff you can keep it as an object and pass it around from one processor to another.

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is:  `exchange.getIn().setBody(myClass);` without `toString()` does not log the object in the log component in ${body}. It logs the original XML message body as it was before unmarshalling. And when I add a new component after log in the route, it uses the xml-Body not the JAXB-Object as input.

Comment: I assume you have added the jaxb file in your classpath that refers to the correct dataformat? See the example camel-jaxb here. https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-jaxb

Comment: In my pom.xml I added the camel-jaxb dependency.

Comment: Not the dependency, but the jaxb file that says which class to map to.You need a jaxb dataformat file. It is a simple text file that includes the name of your class i.e. your MyClass. See the link here for an example : https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-jaxb/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org/apache/camel/dataformat

Comment: Ah ok, and do you know in which directory I have to copy this file. Simply into the resources or in the same folder where my JAXB objects are?

Comment: Resources should be fine as long it is in your classpath.